# Syntax for multiple "or" statements to set a CSS class

Tags: php, class, if-statement, insert, switch-statement

I'm quite new to PHP. The problem statement is, I need to insert a CSS class into the nav on specific pages.  Here's the way I have it now:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top scrolling-navbar 
<?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === 'index.php' || basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === 'shop.php'  || basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === 'news.php') { echo "navbar-transparent"; } ?>
">
```

It works but it feels messy.  I'm going to continue to research it (perhaps a switch statement is better?). Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I would assign `navbar-transparent` to a variable then output in the `class` list. That would be a bit cleaner, and use `in_array`.

Comment: @user3783243 To build on that approach, you could actually define an array of classes and output those. This could be especially useful if you have multiple conditional classes. For instance: `$classes=["navbar", "navbar-expand-md", ... ]` `class="<?= htmlentities(implode(' ', $classes)) ?>"`

Comment: @akenion - can you tease that one out some more please?  I see kinda where it's going but would love more information.

Comment: @SteveShead sure. It's really a simple concept that I have utilized on various occasions and can work well(and be easier to read) with complex conditional classes. I'll write it up in another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a value is in a set, an easy option is to use the [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array) function.

```php
if(in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), ['index.php', 'shop.php', 'news.php']))
```

Comment: That worked - thank you.  Not sure why I didn't think of an array - too new to this I guess! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with more complex conditional classes or lots of dynamic attributes, you can consider defining these in PHP arrays and dynamically building the entire class string rather than having various inline conditionals.

For instance:

```php
<?php
$classes=["navbar", "navbar-expand-md", "navbar-light", "fixed-top", "scrolling-navbar"];
if(in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), ['index.php', 'shop.php', 'news.php']))
    $classes[]="navbar-transparent"; //Equivalent to array_push($classes, "navbar-transparent")
?>
<nav class="<?= implode(' ', $classes) ?>"></nav>
```

You can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) to convert the array to a space-delimited list. If the classes contain user-input or otherwise questionable values, you should use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities) as well to escape the output.

You could even go as far as to build all of your attributes as a multidimensional associative array and output that. This approach is likely excessive for many applications, but could be practical for instance in a more complex templating or component framework.

```
<?php
    function encodeAttributes(array $attributes): string{
        $encoded="";
        foreach($attributes as $key=>$value){
            $encoded.=' '.htmlentities($key);
            if($value!==null){ //Allow for attributes without values(for instance disabled or checked)
                if(is_array($value))
                    $value=implode(' ', $value);
                $encoded.='="'.htmlentities($value).'"';
            }
        }
        return $encoded;
    }
    $attributes=[
        "id"=>"main_nav",
        "class"=>["navbar", "navbar-expand-md", "navbar-light", "fixed-top", "scrolling-navbar"]
    ];
?>
<nav<?= encodeAttributes($attributes) ?>></nav>
```

Comment: @SteveShead is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes - thank you. My only follow on question would be what would happen when a class is injected by javascript? Since the array is outputting the same thing would it matter?  For instance, once you scroll the page the class `top-nav-collapse` is added to change the background color from transparent to white.

Comment: @SteveShead This will work perfectly fine with classes injected via JavaScript; the browser will not know the difference. This PHP is just building output HTML that would be exactly the same as if written directly. For the first example, the browser is just going to see this: `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top scrolling-navbar navbar-transparent"></nav>` All of the server-side processing is completely transparent to the client.